# Sapply operation with multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to add a field in dataframe using the values in other columns depending on the condition in another column.

```
df <- data.frame(condition= c("startBin>7 & startBin<=12 & endBin>25 & endBin<=30","(startBin<=7 | startBin>12) & (endBin<=25 | endBin>30)","(startBin>7 & startBin<=12) & (endBin<=25 | endBin>30)","(startBin<=7 | startBin>12) & endBin>25 & endBin<=30"),
                            startBin = c(1,1,1,1), endBin = c(26,26,26,26), exprTemp=c("One","Two","Three","Four"))
```

I want to create a column "check" with value = 1 if the condition in "condition" column is satisfied. Thus, I want the updated dataframe as:

```
 df <- data.frame(condition= c("startBin>7 & startBin<=12 & endBin>25 & endBin<=30","(startBin<=7 | startBin>12) & (endBin<=25 | endBin>30)","(startBin>7 & startBin<=12) & (endBin<=25 | endBin>30)","(startBin<=7 | startBin>12) & endBin>25 & endBin<=30"),
                            startBin = c(1,1,1,1), endBin = c(26,26,26,26), exprTemp=c("One","Two","Three","Four"), check=c(0,0,0,1))
```

Note that the value of check is 1 for the last record for which the condition is true.

I tried the following:

```
df$check <- eval(parse(text=paste0("ifelse(",df$condition,",1, '')",sep="")),df)
```

but it returned check = 1 for all rows as eval evaluates only the last condition.

Comment: It really isn't clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Updated for more details

Comment: The conditions are different for each row. I think I have to use the strings because this script builds a file which is used by a software to estimate a model.

Comment: Sorry, I misread it.  I thought the conditions were the same for each row.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code :

```
df <- data.frame(startBin = c(1,1,1,1), endBin = c(26,26,26,26), exprTemp=c("One","Two","Three","Four")) 

condition= c("startBin>7 & startBin<=12 & endBin>25 & endBin<=30","(startBin<=7 | startBin>12) & (endBin<=25 | endBin>30)","(startBin>7 & startBin<=12) & (endBin<=25 | endBin>30)","(startBin<=7 | startBin>12) & endBin>25 & endBin<=30")
parsedcond=(parse(text = condition))

newcol=logical(nrow(df))
for(i in 1:nrow(df))
 newcol[i] <- with(df, eval(parsedcond[i]))[i]

    df <- data.frame(df, newcol)
> df
  startBin endBin exprTemp newcol
1        1     26      One  FALSE
2        1     26      Two  FALSE
3        1     26    Three  FALSE
4        1     26     Four   TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I tried going row-by-row but it was too slow. I have several thousands of records and it was not practical to go record by record.

Comment: hi, and you have single condition for each row ? does conditions repeat itselfs ?

Comment: Conditions repeat. Some of the conditions repeat for close to 100 times.